# Disable default Dashboards in the Prometheus Community Helm Chart

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, grafana, kubernetes-helm

I deployed the [kube-prometheus-stack](https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/tree/main/charts/kube-prometheus-stack) helm chart. While this chart offers a really nice starting point it has lots of default dashboards which I do not want to use. In the *values.yaml* of the chart, there is an option *defaultDashboardsEnabled: true*, which seems to be what I am looking for but if I set it to false using the code below in my values file, which I mount into the helm chart, the dashboards are still there. Does anyone know why this does not work?

A possibility which I thought of is that the chart has both a subchart called *grafana* and an option  *grafana*, but I do not know how I could fix it or test if this is the issue.

```
grafana: 
  defaultDashboardsEnabled: false
```

Comment: Have you tried to pull the repo (`helm pull`) locally and just remove the `grafana` directory from the template?

Comment: Yes, that should work but I would rather stick to this Grafana version and understand how to modify the helm chart.

Comment: How about [setting](https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/blob/f551c35d120cc74b774a46b8160904af7bc57135/charts/kube-prometheus-stack/values.yaml#L576) `grafana.enable:` to `false` in values.yml? Just tested this and it does not install grafana with this flag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I`m placing this answer to better visibility as community might interested in other solutions.

- First way would be [setting](https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/blob/f551c35d120cc74b774a46b8160904af7bc57135/charts/kube-prometheus-stack/values.yaml#L576) `grafana.enable:` to false in `values.yaml`.

```sh
## Using default values from https://github.com/grafana/helm-charts/blob/main/charts/grafana/values.yaml
grafana:
  enabled: true
```

With this your chart will not install `grafana`.

- Another way would be to `helm pull` the chart to your local directory and then just delete the `template.grafana` directory (to launch the chart locally you just need to `helm install <name> ./prometheus-stack`)

Comment: The question was how to avoid the default example dashboards being deployed, so only yours appear in the list of dashboards, not removing the full Grafana installation.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue by removing the namespace where Grafana was located. Apparently, there has been some resource left which was not removed by uninstalling the helm chart.

Edit:
The problem seems to be with the configmaps. It appears that in some of these the old configuration is saved even though it has already been changed in the helm chart. Removing the Grafana deployment and all the config maps in the regarding namespace worked for me.
Surely it is not necessary to remove all configmaps but I did not have the time to find out which one is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue and the way I resolved it was to remove the respective config maps which have been generated by the kube-prometheus-stack helm chart.

```
kubectl delete cm $CONFIG_MAP -n $NAMESPACE
```

The config maps usually named the same as the chart title.
In case you're unsure which config map contains which chart, you can just check it with (in my case I saved the entire chart in monitoring namespace)

```
kubectl get cm $CONFIG_MAP -oyaml -n $NAMESPACE
```

The config map contains the entire dashboard JSON where you can find the chart title. You can also use this JSON to import it seperately again in a different folder other than general, since provisioned dashboards cannot be moved and the permissions for the general folder cannot be edited.

Though, I am not sure if these config maps are still referenced somewhere redundantly after deletion.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create Namespace
2. kubectl create namespace
3. helm repo add prometheus-community https://prometheus-community.github.io/helm-charts
4. helm repo update
5. helm install prometheus prometheus-community/kube-prometheus-stack  --set grafana.enabled=false
6. helm upgrade --install -f <prometheus.yaml>  prometheus prometheus-community/kube-prometheus-stack --namespace  --set grafana.enabled=false